# Spark: Checking history of Rows in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have patient data like in this format

```
+---+-----+----+----------+
| id| name|code|      date|
+---+-----+----+----------+
|  1|Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|
|  3|Shaun|B120|2010-10-29|
|  2|Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|
|  4| John|B121|2011-09-29|
|  5| John|B120|2011-09-30|
|  6| John|B111|2012-09-30|
|  7| John|B121|2013-09-29|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

I want to check for every row with code B121 that if in history code B120 is applied on the patient or not
if applied set level to 1 otherwise 2 and level 0 for rows with code B120. After that result should look like this.

**In MySQL I used cursor to do that.**

```
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
| id| name|code|      date|level|
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
|  3|Shaun|B120|2010-10-29|    0|
|  2|Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|    1|
|  1|Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|    1|
|  6| John|B111|2012-09-30|    0|
|  5| John|B120|2011-09-30|    0|
|  4| John|B121|2011-09-29|    2|
|  7| John|B121|2013-09-29|    1|
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
```

**Edited**: I have add new row with code B111 but I want to check history with  code B120.

I tried this solution

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date")
val lagCol = lag(col("date"), 1).over(window)

val pDF = df.withColumn("level", lagCol);
```

But it give the following result

```
 id   name   code   date         level
 1    Shaun  B121   2012-03-21   2011-02-14
 2    Shaun  B121   2011-02-14   2010-10-19
 3    Shaun  B120   2010-10-19   Null
 5    John   B121   2013-09-29   2011-09-29
 4    John   B121   2011-09-29   Null
```

It check the previous row whether it is code B120 or B121 but I want to check previous row with code B120.
I don't know how to use lag function properly. How I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lag` function on `Window` function would make your requirement complicated.

Given the `dataframe` as

```
+---+-----+----+----------+
|id |name |code|date      |
+---+-----+----+----------+
|1  |Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|
|2  |Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|
|3  |Shaun|B120|2010-10-19|
|4  |John |B121|2011-09-29|
|5  |John |B121|2013-09-29|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

You can use following logic

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("code", "date")

df.withColumn("temp", first("code").over(windowSpec))
    .withColumn("level", when($"temp" === "B120" && $"code" === "B121", 1).otherwise(when($"temp" === "B120" && $"code" === "B120", 0).otherwise(lit(2))))
    .drop("temp")
```

Which should give you

```
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
|id |name |code|date      |level|
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
|3  |Shaun|B120|2010-10-19|0    |
|2  |Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|1    |
|1  |Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|1    |
|4  |John |B121|2011-09-29|2    |
|5  |John |B121|2013-09-29|2    |
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
```

**Updated to meet the additional requirements**

Given the following `dataframe`

```
+---+-----+----+----------+
|id |name |code|date      |
+---+-----+----+----------+
|1  |Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|
|2  |Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|
|3  |Shaun|B120|2010-10-29|
|4  |John |B121|2011-09-29|
|5  |John |B120|2011-09-30|
|6  |John |B111|2012-09-30|
|7  |John |B121|2013-09-29|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

You can create a `udf` function to meet the rquirement as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def updateLevel = udf((array: mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]) => {
  val containsB120 = array.filter(ar => ar.contains("B120")).map(ar => (ar(1), ar(2)))
  var code = ""
  var date = "1970-01-01"
  if(containsB120.size > 0) {
    code = containsB120(0)._1
    date = containsB120(0)._2
  }
  val returnArray = array.map(row => {
    println(row(2), date, code)
    if(java.sql.Date.valueOf(row(2)).getTime > java.sql.Date.valueOf(date).getTime && code == "B120" && row(1) == "B121") {
      Array(row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2).toString, "1")
    }
    else if(java.sql.Date.valueOf(row(2)).getTime <= java.sql.Date.valueOf(date).getTime && row(1) == "B121" ) {
      Array(row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2).toString, "2")
    }
    else {
      Array(row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2).toString, "0")
    }
  })
  returnArray
})
```

Then before calling the `udf` function `array` and `collect_list` functions are called and after `udf` function is applied, `explode` function is applied to get the final required `dataframe`.

```
df.orderBy("date").withColumn("tempArray", array("id", "code", "date"))
    .groupBy("name")
    .agg(collect_list("tempArray").as("tempArray"))
    .withColumn("tempArray", explode(updateLevel($"tempArray")))
    .select($"tempArray"(0).as("id"), $"name", $"tempArray"(1).as("code"), $"tempArray"(2).as("date"), $"tempArray"(3).as("level"))
```

You should have final `dataframe` as

```
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
|id |name |code|date      |level|
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
|3  |Shaun|B120|2010-10-29|0    |
|2  |Shaun|B121|2011-02-14|1    |
|1  |Shaun|B121|2012-03-21|1    |
|4  |John |B121|2011-09-29|2    |
|5  |John |B120|2011-09-30|0    |
|6  |John |B111|2012-09-30|0    |
|7  |John |B121|2013-09-29|1    |
+---+-----+----+----------+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanx. Can you provide some link from where I can read these things.

Comment: Its all about combining the knowledge and options you have. Practice,
 practice and practice. [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) will help you. I repeat its all about logical thinking.

Comment: If I add a new row with another code B111 then first function will give B111 but I need to check B120 so in this case what I will do.

Comment: can you update question with input and expected ouput ?

Comment: Or you can ask another question with additional requirements. this question is solved for what your requirement was. :)

Comment: Edited. Please see that

Comment: why is the seventh row's level is 1 and sixth as 2?

Comment: Because 6th row date is 2011-09-29 and there is no B120 in history but 7th row date is 2013-09-29 and B120 is performed in history with date 2011-09-30

Comment: now it seems that your requirement is totally different than what you posted earlier :)

Comment: If B120 is performed on the same date or in history then marked the B121 as level 1 otherwise level 2 and all other code as level 0

Comment: this is final requirement.Please help. It is urgent

Comment: Let me see what I can do about it.

Comment: Updated my answer :) please have a look

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. Your solution is perfect for my problems and also after looking at your code I get the idea to some level to solve problem with spark

Comment: great to hear that :) If you had asked another question I would have earned 25 points more :P hehe just kidding. take care